# Issue with downloading informatica powercenter from oracle cloud edelivery

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I googled up same question and many post suggested to download from oracle website but i am not finding it in edelivery. can someone guide me how to search and download from the new oracle cloud delivery website following  required components-oracle business intelligence data warehouse administration console 11g and informatica powercenter and powerconnect adapters 9.5..
I am trying to setup informatica powercenter to do some hands on practise..
i have installed oracle 11g already.. need other parts but not finding them on oracle cloud delivery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have Informatica 9.6.1 on the Oracle edelivery website. I don't think you will get the 9.5.1 version. However, 9.6.1 should solve your purpose just as well.

Here are some screenshots to help you download the software. First login to the Oracle edelivery website.

Search for "PowerCenter"

[image]

Select Platform:

[image]

[image]

Click Continue. Again click Continue on the next screen, accept the terms and conditions and you will have the download links. The total size is 6.5 GB split across 4 zip files.

Comment: Thanks for info. Do I need oracle business intelligence data warehouse administration console for 11 g also or  download you mentioned willl be all. I hv setup oracle 11g already. If yes pls point to which version of oracle business intelligence data warehouse administration console as I am finding many different version for Oracle business intelligence in cloud edelivery site..

Comment: If you have Oracle database up and running, you do not need anything else.

Comment: Thanks Samiks. i have one more issue.. i am trying to create a ODBC connection for oracle 11g. Since Informatica requires 32 bit ODBC connection ; i am logging into ODBC 32 bit -c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe ; there when i click Add ;i  do not see my oracle_home as source in window.. how can i  make oracle to appear as source. oracle is coming for ODBC 64 bit one... i installed oracle client also.tnsnames.ora has correct entry for my database.. what else i should check ?

Comment: I am using win7 64 bit .. oracle is 11g R2.. infromatica is 9.6.1,,